# Groovy and final properties how to set with a Map?

Tags: grails, groovy

i am trying to set final properties in Groovy source (used in a Grails project) and following some examples but somehow i does not seem to work and i cannot find out why..

```
class Foo {

  final x

  Foo(Map m=[:]) {
    m.each { key, value -> this.@"$key" = value }
  }
}

def foo = new Foo(x:1)
```

I am getting the error:

`Cannot set the property 'x' because the backing field is final.`

According to some posts found on the internet this should work.
Why does fail how can is set the properties via a map when using a final field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve the result you seek by using the @Immutable annotation

```
@Immutable
class Foo {
  def x
}
```

Then this can be called as

```
def foo = new Foo([:])
```

or

```
def foo = new Foo(x:42)
```

and then later

```
foo.x = 43
```

causes

```
ERROR groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException:
Cannot set readonly property: y for class: Foo
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i am using it right now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your constructor with a Map argument doesn't work, but this constructor does:

```
class Foo {

  final x

  Foo(x) {
    this.x = x
  }
}

def foo = new Foo(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, You should use @MapConstructor annotation

```
@ToString(includePackage = false, includeNames = true)
@MapConstructor
class A {
    @Final
    String x
    int y

}
def a = new A(x: 'david', y: 12)
println "a = $a"
```